# trying to graph a funtion in mat lab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to graph some functions in matlab this is my first time using mat lab I was able to graph the first 3 funtions fine but the one called funcmain is giving me trouble
the error I am getting is unrecognized funtion or variable 't'

here is my code:

```
function r = ur(t)

      %  ur.m - generates the unit ramp function r(t)
      %
      %  Gordon E. Carlson  University of Missouri-Rolla

         r = 0.*(t<0) + t.*(t>=0);
 
func1 = @(t) 2*t;
func2 = @(t) -2*t-4;
func3 = @(t) 2*t-8;
funcmain= @(t) 2*r(t)-4*r(t-1)+4*r(t-3)-2*r(t-4);
fplot(func1)
hold on
fplot(func2)
fplot(func3)
fplot(funcmain)
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable `t` is an input parameter which can be indicated by adding the `@(t)` to the beginning of the equation. All anonymous functions require the input parameters to be indicated within the `@(Input_Parameters)` section of the equation.

```
r = @(t) 0.*(t<0) + t.*(t>=0);

funcmain= @(t) 2*r(t)-4*r(t-1)+4*r(t-3)-2*r(t-4);
fplot(funcmain)
```

[image: Graphing/Plotting Anonymous Functions]